# npm task not creating node_modules folder in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, npm, azure-pipelines, node-modules, quill

This is not a node project but rather an MVC Web Application. Objective is to bundle a Quill.js library via npm steps in the Azure pipeline.

Problem: node_modules folder with needed code and dependencies is not getting generated in the pipeline.

package.json is configured such that deploying the solution locally in a fresh location with only an "npm install" will recreate node_modules folder with all the needed files and dependencies so that everything works beautifully.

Having trouble duplicating this process via Azure Pipeline tasks, however. node_modules folder with the needed goodies is not getting created. Have done some experimentation but here’s the sequence that makes the most sense to me:

Use NuGet NuGet Restore
VsTest – testAssemblies
Use Node 8.x
npm install (task is set to run in same project folder where package.json lives)
Build solution
Several other tasks…

package.json looks like this...

```
{
  ...
     ,
  "dependencies": {
    "quill": "^1.3.7"
  }
}
```

But node_modules is not getting created as it does in local.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this case. You can add another npm task, and select **Custom** command. " then enter `npm install quill` in **Command and argument** to install quill specifically.

Comment: Thanks for trying to repro, @Levi Lu-MSFT. Encouraging that you are getting node_modules folder via build pipeline tasks. Yes, I have tried explicitly calling "npm install quill" in npm task after "npm install" task, but that did not help (and i would expect "npm install" to suffice since package.json specifies quill). I would like to better understand the delta between my configuration and yours.

Comment: I posted my configuration in below. Could you post your npm task's configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the info, @LeviLu-MSFT. My npm task configuration is identical to yours, with the "Working folder that contains package.json" value set to the folder that contains the package,json and where the node_modules folder _should_ be created. package.json is essentially same as yours as well. Trying to determine what may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Had incorrectly identified the problem. It turned out that the node_modules folder was in fact being loaded by npm on the build machine but the build solution wasn't picking up the folder or its contents to be included in the artifact.

Answer found on this blog post:

https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/08/11/how-to-add-gulp-output-or-bowernpm-packages-to-webdeploy-package/

Solution was to manually edit the project file to add a custom build target, adding the below to the csproj file for the project containing the package.json.

```
  <Target Name="AddNpmOutput">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="node_modules\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>node_modules\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      AddNpmOutput;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      AddNpmOutput;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: It is great you worked it out. You can mark above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple package.json and I configured my npm task as below screen.

```
{
  "name": "service--whoami-sample-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Azure Functions sample for the Serverless framework",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\"",
    "start": "func host start"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "azure",
    "serverless"
  ],
  "dependencies": { "quill": "^1.3.7"}
}
```

[image]

I run the pipeline against my self-hosted agent. From the screenshot you see the quill got installed.

[image]